# Estimate the integral of $(1+x^2)^{-\alpha}$, where $\alpha>1/2$

Tags: calculus, inequality, integral-inequality

I'm reading a proof of a theorem, and there's one step I couldn't understand why. It said that for all $a>0$ and $\alpha>1/2$, 
$$
\int_{a}^{\infty}(1+x^2)^{-\alpha} \ \mathrm dx \leq2^{2\alpha-1}\left(1+\frac{1}{2\alpha-1}\right)(1+a^2)^{-\alpha+1/2}.
$$
Could anybody give me a hint about this inequality? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AlexR For $\alpha = 1$ and $a = 1$, the left-hand side is $\pi/4$, is it not?  Or for $\alpha =1$ and $a \to 0$, the right-hand side is $4$.

Comment: @Dr.MV My bad I misread the RHS. I was thinking about $a=0, \alpha=1$ yielding $\frac\pi2 \le 2^1 (1+\frac11) (1+0^2)^{-1/2} = 4$.

Comment: @AlexR ..;. and $4\le 4 \sqrt{2}$.  But, check the case for $a=1$.  The bound is even more crude.  $\pi/4 \le 4 \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @AlexR Could you explain why $(1+x^2)^{-\alpha}\leq(1+a^2)^{-\alpha}x^{-\alpha/2}$? I'm sorry I don't see it.

Comment: The $(1+a^2)^{-\alpha}$ was an act of randomness because of the RHS. The other part contained a typo, but is simple: $(1+x^2)^{-\alpha} \le x^{-2\alpha}$ and since $\alpha > \frac12$, $(1+x^2)^{-\alpha} \le 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to estimate:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1+a^2}{1+(a+x)^2}\right)^{\alpha}\,dx&=&\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{2a}{1+a^2}x+\frac{1}{1+a^2}x^2}\right)^{\alpha}\,dx\\&=&\sqrt{1+a^2}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\left(\frac{1}{1+z^2+\frac{2a}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}z}\right)^{\alpha}\,dz\end{eqnarray*} $$
and assuming $a> 0$ and $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$ the last integral is upper bounded by:
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{(1+z^2)^\alpha}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}\cdot\frac{\Gamma\left(\alpha-\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\alpha\right)}\leq\frac{\sqrt{\pi\alpha}}{2\alpha-1},$$
much better. Putting all together, I get:

> $$ \int_{a}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(1+x^2)^\alpha}\leq (1+a^2)^{\frac{1}{2}-\alpha}\frac{\sqrt{\pi\alpha}}{2\alpha-1},$$

tighter and simpler than your inequality.

Comment: I think there are some typos in the second line?

Comment: @Liu: I put $x=z\cdot\sqrt{1+a^2}$.

Comment: My bad. I see that now.

Comment: @Liu: maybe it is the case to change the names for the parameters - I had a hard time in distinguishing $a$ from $\alpha$ and type everything right.

Comment: Could you give me some details for $\frac{\Gamma(\alpha-1/2)}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\leq \frac{\sqrt{\alpha}}{\alpha-1/2}$? I'm not really familiar to Gamma and Beta functions...

Comment: @Liu: such inequality follows from the Euler product for the $\Gamma$ function or the log-convexity of $\Gamma$ (Bohr-Mollerup theorem). A quick look at Wikipedia will give you everything. It can be proved also as a consequence of the Wallis product.